# Does linux kernel publish process state change events?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm running a multi threaded java application. I would like to know how well my application is taking advantage of multi-core cpu. Is there a tool or api in Linux, that provides the following information?

process id, thread name, state, core, time.

Does linux kernel publish process state change events?

Comment: Yes, there's literally a TON of information published via the /proc file system. Exactly where the state information want is, I don't know, but probably in the per-process /proc subfolders

Comment: @MarcB /proc/ does have tons of information. But we don't want to poll these files to see the process state changes. We can miss information if the thread goes from R->S->R-S->R between a polling period. The above change will be treated as simply "R" with polling. But, if we listen on events it gives the true picture of what happens to the threads.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ftrace or SystemTap. Or if you want fancy graphs, [KernelShark](https://lwn.net/Articles/425583/).